# inserting multiple values for an entity at once

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've 3 tables:
1. userTABLE
- USERNAME (jone)

1. productTABLE

   - prd_name (prd1, prd2, prd3)
2. paidTABLE

   - USERNAME
   - prd_name
   - paid_amt

My query is to insert amount paid by jone for the 3 products. 
One way is: I've to seperately insert paid amts by jone for every product he buys.

```
create proc paid @USERNAME varchar, @prd_name varchar, @paid_amt int
as
insert into paidTABLE values (@USERNAME, @prd_name, @paid_amt  )
```

Is there any way to insert the value of paid_amt at once in the table by jone for the 3 products
i.e in one stored procedure statement I could insert the amount paid by jone for the 3 product he bought.

Comment: Who's `jone`? Why create a procedure for this? Simply do it in a transaction, which gives you an atomic insert, even though it's 3 separate insert queries.

Comment: jone - username. will you explain your a little more. THANK YOU

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Marc - do it in a transaction, but if you really want a single statement, then you could do:

```
insert into paid (username, prd_name, paid_amt)
select 'jone', 'prd1', 10
union all
select 'jone', 'prd2', 20
union all
select 'jone', 'prd3', 30
```